# Creating tNode class for a binary tree

Tags: c++, class, binary-tree

I was provided with the following definition for the `tNode class` for a binary tree:

```
#ifndef TNODE_H
#define TNODE_H

template <typename T>
class tNode<T>{
public:
    T nodeValue;
    tNode<T> *left, *right, *parent;

    tNode<T>(const& T value, tNode<T> l = NULL, tNode<T> r = NULL, tNode<T> p){
        nodeValue = value;
        left = l;
        right = r;
        parent = p;
    }
};

#endif
```

I am getting the following errors when compiling my main.cpp (with nothing within the main):

```
tNode.h:5:7: error: ‘tNode’ is not a class template
 class tNode<T>{
       ^~~~~
tNode.h:10:18: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘T’ with no type [-fpermissive]
  tNode<T>(const& T value, tNode<T> *l = NULL, tNode<T> *r = NULL, tNode<T>    *p){
                  ^
tNode.h:10:18: error: declaration of ‘const int& T’ shadows template parameter
tNode.h:4:11: note: template parameter ‘T’ declared here
 template <typename T>
           ^~~~~~~~
tNode.h:10:20: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘value’
  tNode<T>(const& T value, tNode<T> *l = NULL, tNode<T> *r = NULL, tNode<T> *p){
                    ^~~~~
tNode.h: In constructor ‘tNode<T>::tNode(const int&)’:
tNode.h:10:18: error: declaration of ‘const int& T’ shadows template parameter
  tNode<T>(const& T value, tNode<T> *l = NULL, tNode<T> *r = NULL, tNode<T> *p){
                  ^
tNode.h:4:11: note: template parameter ‘T’ declared here
 template <typename T>
           ^~~~~~~~
tNode.h:11:15: error: ‘value’ was not declared in this scope
   nodeValue = value;
               ^~~~~
tNode.h:12:10: error: ‘l’ was not declared in this scope
   left = l;
          ^
tNode.h:13:11: error: ‘r’ was not declared in this scope
   right = r;
           ^
tNode.h:14:12: error: ‘p’ was not declared in this scope
   parent = p;
            ^
```

Any help that would give some insight on these errors would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The provided definition is syntactically incorrect.  You probably want to talk to whoever provided it, especially if it was given to more than just you.

Comment: Remove the `<T>` in tNode.h:5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided code is syntactically and semantically incorrect.
Syntactically, a class template follows the syntax `template <class A_Type> class class_name`; note that the generic type `A_Type` is not declared with the class name (as you would do when you later instantiate the template) but after the `template < class ...`-part.
Second, it specifies `tNode *left` as a pointer to this class, whereas the constructor `tNode(const T &value, tNode l = NULL, ...)` does not use a pointer (and also not a reference). This will lead to compiler errors when instantiating the template later on.

The template should look at least something like this:

```
template <class T>
class tNode{
public:
    T nodeValue;
    tNode *left, *right, *parent;

    tNode(const T &value, tNode *l = NULL, tNode *r = NULL, tNode *p = NULL){
        nodeValue = value;
        left = l;
        right = r;
        parent = p;
    }
};
```

Comment: Ahh this works, maybe I missed the `*` when I wrote it down, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong for creating a class template, it should be like this ...

```
template <class type> class class_name {
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Here, `type` is the placeholder type name, which will be specified when a class is instantiated.

Also definition of your constructor

`tNode<T>(const& T value, tNode<T> l = NULL, tNode<T> r = NULL, tNode<T> p)`

doesn't follow the rules for default arguments.

> In a function declaration, Once default value is used for an argument,
>   all subsequent arguments must have a default value.